# Displaying thumbnails in a horizontal layout

Tags: html, css, user-interface, html-table

I want to display a few thumbnails along with their names in a horizontal layout. Since there may be quite a few of these thumbnails, I want the containing div to have a horizontal scroll option. Currently I'm putting each of the thumbnails in a table row, but this causes the last few thumbnails to be squished into each other.
This is my current code:

```
<div class="span12" id="assignment_group_container" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <% @pp.assignment_group.each_with_index do |ag, i| %>   
        <td id="<%= ag[0].gsub(" ", "_") %>" class="span2" >
          <%= image_tag "http://placekitten.com/50/50" %>
          <br/>
          <%= ag[0] %>
        </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how I can get the effect I want?

EDIT: Adding actual HTML generated

```
<div class="span12" id="assignment_group_container" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="Ab_Crunch_Machine" class="span2" >
        <img alt="50" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" />
        <br/>
        Ab Crunch Machine 
      </td>

      Multiple <td> elements...
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide generated HTML, template code is useless to us.

Comment: Added HTML. Just out of curiosity, is there any additional information in the HTML that the eRB template does not provide?

Comment: @user1742188: Not necessarily. But as your issue is restricted to HTML & CSS, your template code isn’t relevant and it could even be a barrier because not everyone knows/understands this template language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you really need is a way to disable wrapping.  This will allow you to ditch tables and there's no need to know in advance how wide anything is.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/weg5rsvz

Markup:

```
<div class="span12" id="assignment_group_container">
  <figure id="Ab_Crunch_Machine">
    <img alt="50" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" />
    <figcaption>Ab Crunch Machine</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <!-- repeat the figure... -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#assignment_group_container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#assignment_group_container figure {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me perfectly. I also had to remove the 'span2' class from the figure tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create horizontal scrolling then your containing div needs to be width 100%.  I'm guessing that whatever this table is in is set to a defined width and once you hit that width it's trying to equally space out within.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ditching the table. Use inline block to display your thumbs. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZepu/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery span12" id="assignment_group_container">
  <div class='inner'>
  <div class='thumb' id='Ab_Crunch Machine'>
    <img alt="50" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" />
    <p>Ab Crunch Machine</p>
  </div>
  <div class='thumb' id='Ab_Crunch Machine'>
   <img alt="50" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" />
   <p>Ab Crunch Machine</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery {
  background: #efefef;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.inner {
  width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are using tables to lay out the thumbnails? Tables should really only be used for tabular data. Maybe floating the thumbnails would be a better choice?

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="whatever" /></li>
    <li><img src="whatever" /></li>
</ul>

ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a list to do this and put the list in a container to enable the scrollbar like so:

HTMl:

```
<div id="thumbs">
  <ul>
    <li>template content</li>
    <li>template content</li>
    <li>template content</li>
    <li>template content</li>
    <li>template content</li>
    <li>template content</li>
    <li>template content</li>
    <li>template content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#thumbs { 
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; }

ul { 
    width: 1000px;
    list-style: none;}

li { float: left; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P6jSh/1/

Of course in reality you may not know how many li elements there will be, so you may not be able to set a fixed width on the ul. If that's the case, you may need to use a small amount of jQuery to find the number of li's, times that by the width of the thumbs and apply that width to the ul.